# regular expression match in linux grep command

Tags: regex, linux

I want to search for a string which matches regex `[A-Z]+(?:19|20)\d\d` in a file in centos.
I am using below command for the same:

`grep -F '[A-Z]+(?:19|20)\d\d' <file_name>`

It does not seem to work.
I ended up escaping `.^$*+?()[{\|` but still no luck.
I wanted to know if am incorrect somewhere, can anyone please help ?

Comment: Why `-F` option? Did you mean to use `-P` ?

Comment: Yes, my bad.. Thanks.. Its working now